# Libertine + newtxmath gaps in big brackets

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, equations

I have a problem when combining Libertine with newtxmath.
When using large brackets in equations the brackets have strange gaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,oneside,a4paper]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
    \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

    \usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\libertine@figurestyle{LF}
    \makeatother
    \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\libertine@figurestyle{OsF}
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            




    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \gamma_{1,i}=\dfrac{\left[\dfrac{1}{K\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}R_{ij}}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}\sum\limits_{n=(j-1)K}^{jK-1}r_1^2[n]R_{ij}\right]-\left[\dfrac{1}{K\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}|R_{ij}-1|}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}\sum\limits_{n=(j-1)K}^{jK-1}r_1^2[n]|R_{ij}-1|\right]}{\dfrac{1}{K\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}|R_{ij}-1|}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_s}\sum\limits_{n=(j-1)K}^{jK-1}r_1^2[n]|R_{ij}-1|}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

The gaps do show up on print, albeit not as visible as on screen, so it's not just a viewer issue. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: that is only a problem with the pdf-viewer and the magnification. It will be okay if printed.

Comment: I already mentioned that it also shows up on print, proof coming up.

Comment: oh, yes you are right!

Comment: It seems a bug in the metrics for the "repeater" character.

Comment: The bug doesn't seem limited to the `libertine` font option case, as it occurs without the `libertine` option being set.

Comment: Your printer resolution is too good `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of versions 1.20 of `newtxmath` and 1.09 of `newpxmath` (both dated 2014/02/02) the problem should be solved.

From the README of the `newtx` suite:

> Changes in version 1.20
>   Corrected issues with extensible delimiters created inadvertently in 1.18.

From the README of the `newpx` suite:

> Changes in version 1.09
>   In tandem with newtx 1.20, corrected some issues with extensible delimiters introduced inadvertently in newtx 1.18.